# React - Elements UI - Dropdown hidden by wrapping div size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm using [Elements UI](https://elemefe.github.io/element-react/index#/en-US/dropdown) and tailwind css in my React app. I have a component that represents a card section and I have multiple stacked vertically. Each of those card elements has a dropdown menu in it, which however isn't fully rendering since it seems to be restricted by the surrounding component's width (see screenshot below). I tried adding a z-index on the dropdown and the items, but that didn't work. Does anybody know how to make it overlay over the other card components?

This is the dropdown component (= PaymentDropdown in the second listing)

```
<Dropdown
    className="flex items-center"
    trigger={'click'}
    onCommand={onCommand}
    menu={
        <Dropdown.Menu className="z-20">
           <Dropdown.Item command="mark_as_paid" className="flex items-center min-w-180 w-180 py-8 px-16">
              <div className="flex items-center justify-center rounded-full w-16 h-16">
                   <CheckedIcon />
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center ml-12">
                  <p className="leading-none">
                      <span className="text-text">Mark as paid</span>
                  </p>
              </div>
          </Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
   }
>
    <Button onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} loading={loading} className="w-160">
         Payment Options <i className="el-icon-caret-bottom el-icon--right"></i>}
    </Button>
</Dropdown>
```

and this is the surrounding card component:

```
<div onClick={onClick}>
    <Card className="cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100">
        <div className="flex items-start sm:items-center">
            ...    
            <div className="hidden md:block px-34">
                <div className="btn-wrapper">
                   <PaymentDropdown/>
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
    </Card>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow-auto` on the card element solved the issue.